# Specific local account missing after joining domain

Tags: user-accounts, windows-domain

After joining a Windows 7 computer to a Windows 2008 domain, one of the local accounts is missing, while the others still are acessible. If remove the computer from the domain, that specific local account becomes available again. Someone has an explanation to this behavior?

Norberto

Comment: Does the local account disappear from the Local Users and Groups (int compmgmt.msc) completely? Does it still show up as a member of the groups it used to be in?

Comment: @Hyppy - I tried to reproduce the problem in a VM without success. I will need to go back to the computer where the problem ocurred for further investigation.